# Start a service in docker container failed,with error: Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager

Tags: docker, dbus, systemd

I installed docker image and built a image successfully.

When I ssh to the container and run the command `service xxx start`, an error popped:

> service nginfra start
>
> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start nginfra.service /sbin/service:
>   line 79: /bin/systemctl: No such file or directory

Actually, `fakesystemd` is installed in the container instead of `systemd`.

So I removed `fakesystemd` and installed `systemd` with the command:
    yum swap -- remove fakesystemd -- install systemd systemd-libs

But I still can't start the service:

> service nginfra start
>
> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start nginfra.service Failed to get
>   D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.

Does anyone ever meet and solved this issue?

Comment: Please learn how to format posts to make it readable for others.

Comment: If you share your Dockerfile, it might be easier for others to help

Answer (score 9):

I've managed to fix this issue in a CentOS:7 Docker container.
I've followed mainly [the Guide on CentOS Docker image project](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/centos#systemd-integration).

```
FROM centos:7

ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

# Install anything. The service you want to start must be a SystemD service.

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Now, build the image, and run it using at least the following arguments to `docker run` command: `-v /run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro`

Then main point is that `/usr/sbin/init` must be the first process inside the Docker container.

So if you want to use a custom script that executes some commands before running `/usr/sbin/init`, launch it at the end of your script using `exec /usr/sbin/init` (in a bash script).

Here is an example:

```
ADD cmd.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cmd.sh

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/cmd.sh"]
```

And here is the content of `cmd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do some stuffs

exec /usr/sbin/init # To correctly start D-Bus thanks to https://forums.docker.com/t/any-simple-and-safe-way-to-start-services-on-centos7-systemd/5695/8
```

You could have `System is booting up. See pam_nologin(8)` if your using the PAM system, in that case, delete `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd-nologin.conf` in your `Dockerfile` because it creates the file `/var/run/nologin` which generates this specific error.

Comment: From https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7459#issuecomment-283888347, Valuable info. Reading the Guide and trying with centos7&Dockerfile, the same error didn't go away. Seems my docker version 1.12 is too old, I gave up and fallback to `run --privillaged`.

Comment: Not sure why, but it seems it's still failing in my case - see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7459#issuecomment-341907198 `Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted` and a `[!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems, freezing.`

Comment: @loretoparisi I had this message when forgetting to add `-v /run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro` to `docker run` did you have it?

Answer (score 6):

This is [known issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7459) with `systemd`-based OSes inside Docker containers.

Short answer: as well as replacing `fakesystemd` with `systemd` you need to attach `/sys/fs/cgroup` as a read-only volume into the container, build the image and then run it in "privileged" mode.

This is [the best guide I've found for this](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/centos#systemd-integration). It uses Centos as the example, but should work with any `systemd`-based OS.

Comment: So if your running Docker on top of Mac or Windows, then your basically screwed???  :(

Comment: @jerseybean No, this issue is with the OS that is running inside the Docker container, not with the type of host that the container is running on.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in a Windows docker environment (using RHEL and CentOS as container OS).