# In fedora container systemctl gives Failed to get D-Bus connection

Tags: docker, fedora

When I in a fedora container systemctl use, I get:

Failed to get D-Bus connection:: Unknown error -1

Does someone know how to fix this? Or can systemctl not be used in a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `systemctl` command talks to `systemd` over a DBus connection.  It is unlikely that you are running `systemd` in your container, so `systemctl` has nothing with which to talk.

While it is *possible* to run `systemd` in a container, doing so is often (but not always!) a sign that you need to rethink the architecture of your containers.

Comment: Indeed, systemd was not running. Now I understand the error! Why is it not good to use systemctl in containers? Because for example instead of `systemctl enable sshd`, I have to do `ssh-keygen -A` and then `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

Comment: Running a service manager inside a container hides service errors (e.g, "sshd crashed") from the host, which in turn makes it difficult for higher-level orchestration tools (like kubernetes, or even systemd on the host) to manage things.  It also makes it more likely that someone will stuff a bunch of unrelated services into a container, which can ultimately make them more difficult to scale.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, the standard systemctl needs SystemD. But for a command like "systemctl enable " or starting a service process one actually do that without a running SystemD.

The "systemctl enable" will essentially look into the sshd.service file for a "WantedBy=multi-user.target" clause and then it creates a symlink in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/. Similary, a "systemctl start" will look for the "ExecStart=/usr/bin/sshd" clause in the ssh.service file.

If you do not want look that up and run those parts manually, you could use my systemctl.py helper from the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) which can do the interpretation of systemd service files for you.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed a similar issue, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42534263/535203).

The main idea is to make `/usr/sbin/init` the **first process** inside the container.